# How get category ID of products on wishlist and compare pages

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, helper

I want get category ID of products on wishlist and compare page (on wishlist and compare pages I add products of different categories).

On the helper of my module I write:

```
Mage::registry('current_category');
```

(and then `->getId()`)but I get NULL (on other pages - GOOD!)

When on the helper of my module I write:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLastVisitedCategoryId();
```

I get category Id of last category. It's wrong for me, becouse in wishlist or compare there are product of different categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write function to my block

```
    public function getCategory()
{
    $_item=$this->getProduct();
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
    $ids = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    $category = (isset($ids[0]) ? $ids[0] : null);
    return $category;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add add new Row in catalog/product/compare/list.phtml

header `<th>` field as category id and in detail `<td>` field get the category of product.

You will get array of category ids.

```
$categories=$_item->getCategoryIds()
foreach($categories as $category)
   echo Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category)->getName();
```

In same way you can try for wishlist.